# How to convert 16bits image to 8bits in c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, graphics

I'd like change RGB values in my picture using OpenCV library in C++. I loop through pixels in an image, read R, G, B and change them like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  Mat depth16 = imread("./test.tif",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

  if(depth16.empty()){
    cout<<"image not loaded";
  }
  else{
    cout<<depth16.type()<<endl;
  }

  float scale_factor=1.0/256.0;
  //depth16.convertTo(depth16, CV_8U, scale_factor);

  float step=65536/256;

 uchar r, g, b;
      for (int i = 0; i < depth16.rows; ++i){
        Vec3b* pixel = depth16.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < depth16.cols; ++j){
          r=pixel[j][2];
          g=pixel[j][1];
          b=pixel[j][0];

          depth16.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[2] = step/r+r/2;
          depth16.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[1] = step/g+g/2;
          depth16.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[0] = step/b+b/2;
        }
      }

  namedWindow( "test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow("test",depth16);
  imwrite( "./Gray_Image.tif", depth16 );

  cout<<depth16.type()<<endl;
  waitKey(0);    



  return 0;  
}
```

but only left half of picture change color and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Hi. What's this `step` variable? How is it defined? Actually, can you give the types and definitions of all the variables you're using?

Comment: A note on code style: `pixel` would suggest that is a single pixel, while it is actually an array.

Comment: Point(j, i) would suggest a column-major format, while your traversal order seems to be row-major. Can you verify whether you're perhaps mixing up columns and rows?

Comment: Is it exactly half of your image?

Comment: I added definition of step, but it doesn't matter, always only half picture is change.

Comment: What type is depth16?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly half of image. It's mat type:

Comment: What operation do you actually want to perform on the image ? Maybe there is an inbuilt functionality for doing the same, iterating the whole image is never a good idea as far as performance is concerned.

Comment: This question is impossible/difficult to answer without a complete example that gives the type of the `mat`. Beginner mistakes include getting the internal type of the mat wrong.

Comment: I suppose he's talking about http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr

Comment: I need to convert 16bits tiff image to 8bits image but I haven't use function from library (program for university...). So i want to do this: 
    float scale_factor=1.0/256.0; 
    depth16.convertTo(depth16, CV_8U, scale_factor); 
I know my algorithm is wrong now, but first I try to do anything on this picture...
I'll edite my question and add all code, sorry It's my first question on stack :)